# While loop with functions and if/break statement?

Tags: python

I’m just starting to learn functions and I am practicing on implementing some into my code. Just a simple example... how can I code this to loop properly and break out when the user wants?

```
def profit(i,c):

    gain = c - i

    print('Your profit is:' + '' + str(gain))

def beginning():

    x = float(input("What was your initial  investment?"))

    y = float(input("What is your investment worth now?"))

    profit(x,y)

beginning()

ans = 'y'

while ans == 'y' or ans == 'Y':
    ans = str(input('Would you like to calculate another investment? (Y/N)'))
    beginning()

    if ans != 'y' or ans != 'Y':
        break
```

Comment: `if ans.upper() != 'Y'`, `while ans.upper() != 'Y'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two ways to break out of a while loop. The first way is obviously the `break` statement, kind of like you have done. For it to work correctly, you need to change the condition:

```
if ans != 'y' or ans != 'Y':
    break
```

This will always be true, since `ans` cannot be "y" and "Y" at the same time. You should change it into:

```
if ans not in ["y", "Y"]:
```

Or

```
if ans.upper() != "Y":
```

In your case however, you don't need it at all. Since in both the if statement and the while condition you are checking `ans`, you can get rid of the `if` and just rely on this.

```
while ans.upper() == "Y":
```

This will end the loop automatically when `ans` becomes anything other than "Y" or "y".

The only reason you would use a `break` here is if you wanted to exit the loop immediately, and not complete the current iteration. For example:

```
while ans.upper() == "Y":
    ans = input("Enter selection: ")
    if ans == "I want to stop right now!":
        break
    print("Do other things, even if ans is not Y")
```

In this example, "Do other things" will always be printed regardless of `ans`, unless `ans` is "I want to stop", in which case it won't get printed.

Comment: @chrisz Oops, didn't catch that. I have corrected my answer

Comment: This works, the only issue is with inputting anything other than y or Y results in the loop still continuing.

Comment: Well no, inputting anything other than Y will make the loop stop, either immediately if you used the break, or at the end of the iteration if you went with the condition. Can I see exactly what you're doing?

Comment: I see what's happening, though I can't pinpoint how to fix it.
When the question initially is asked if the user wanted to continue, if an input besides Y is input, it executes beginning() once more before doing so.

Comment: I managed to fix it by moving beginning() after the if statement instead of before and it worked, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

One thing you can do is `ans = ans.capitalize()` after you get the user input. Then remove the `ans != 'y'` since that's causing your loop to break.